# Where can we recycle washing machine and kitchen sink drain water?

Tags: water, drain, code-compliance, water-quality, green

I would like to know the best place or method to recycle drain water from the kitchen and washing machine.

Can we use it for gardening (as it contains soap and oil)? Or it can be added to a Biogas plant?

Comment: Searching for the term "[Greywater](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greywater) recycling", may be helpful.

Comment: Your question may get better results over at the [Sustainable Living](http://sustainability.stackexchange.com) site.

Comment: http://graywatergardening.com/2_Minute_Overview.html

Comment: Yup. Graywater. The key is to use the proper environmentally friendly detergents. Standard laundry detergent, for example, can be rather nasty.

Comment: You know there are filtration systems that take ALL water from your house and purify enough to reuse - yes you can drink your own toilet water with less impurities than you get from the city.  This is more of a question about your setup and cost/choices.